# wiredx alternatives

Tags: windows, x11

http://wiredx.net/download.php

I'd like to give access to some software to users via the X11 protocol. A browser plugin seems the simplest. Are there any alternatives to the above?

Answer (score 1):

[Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is pretty feature-rich and exists as a [portable version](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=419), although not a plugin. You might succeed in doing some preconfiguration for the portable to hand out (or make available as a download) to your users.

Edit: as you referenced Wiredx, there also is [Wierdx](http://www.jcraft.com/weirdx/) which is an open-source java project forking off some old codebase of Wiredx.

Comment: I use Xming all the time. Xming doesn't run in the browser. I need a browser plugin. The reason is to provide a web interface to a network application. I don't want to write a webapp.

Comment: I'll try the open source version.

Comment: I know that Xming won't run in a browser, but as a portable it would not require installation as well, so a simple "download & run" scheme would work similarly well as running a Java application in user's experience. The downside of Weirdx is that development stopped years ago and it was forked off pretty outdated code in the first place. You might even see problems running it on recent Java runtimes.